# Web Essentials 2013 - Slow After Build - Many Directories

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sitecore, web-essentials

We have a sitecore website project in visual studio 2013 that has about 2,800 folders/subfolders.

Whenever we build the project, the IDE freezes up for about 20 seconds after getting the "Build Succeeded" message on the bottom blue bar.

It appears to be related to Web Essentials because when I uninstall it, the problem goes away. Also, we had many more subfolders (5,700 additional). I removed those and the freeze time went down by about 50 seconds. I haven't found another group of folders to remove.

All of the Web Essentials "Compile files on build" options are set to False.

I tried changing various other Web Essential settings to false (including compile on build), nothing fixed it.

I tried changing all settings to the opposite of their default. No effect.

I tried many different options for excluding files via the .jscrc file. (per [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499526/how-can-i-configure-web-essentials-2013-to-ignore-files/21598355#21598355))That did not appear to have any affect. (excludeFiles": [" ** "], excludeFiles": ["**/data/*"] (<-- that was for the 5,700 folders), etc.

Given my settings, I would think that Web Essentials shouldn't be doing anything during or after my build, yet it appears to be.

Does anyone know what it might be doing that would be causing this slow down?

Is anyone else with many sub-folders experiencing this?

Thanks,

Gregory

Comment: I get this issue even without a lot of subfolders

Comment: I found my issue was allowing LESS to compile on build, turning that off fixed the hang up.

Comment: thanks Dan, but it does it even with complie on build turned off

Comment: Did you try turning off all extensions and leaving web essentials on to see if this is really the case?

Comment: @Roland, I think I did. I'm on a deadline right now so I don't want to mess with it too much.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not Microsoft customer support. Contact the Web Essentials team (Mads Kristensen).

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution, but I can't comment yet.
I've been having the same issue recently and finally had time to look into it.

I also narrowed the cause to Web Essentials 2013 (2.5.4 currently), went inside the WebEssentials-Settings.json file at the solution level and basically set everything to false where it was true, which fixed the issue.

After trying to find the specific option(s) that caused it, it ended up being the Markdown compile on build option that was the only 'compile on build' still enabled.

Funnily enough, I don't have any Markdown file in the solution...

Anyway if you've already set all compile on build options to false, maybe tinkering with something else in this file could help?

Comment: Although a strange thing to happen, if it worked for you then I would consider this an answer to the question and not just a comment.