# Visual Studio 2013 - publish minified javascript only

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, publish

**Environment:**

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51209

I have a website project that contains some javascript files.  Visual Studio minifies javascript files automatically -- for example, if the "source" file is called "myscript.js" -- Visual Studio will also create a minified version called: "myscript.min.js" -- which is great...

When I right-click on the file name in Solution Explorer and select "Publish myscript.js" - Visual studio publishes three files:

- myscript.js
- myscript.min.js
- myscript.min.js.map

However, I want to publish ONLY the minified version of the file to the web site -- problem is, if I use the "Exclude From Project" setting (right-click on "myscript.js" -> Exclude From Project"); Visual studio will also exclude the minified version of the source file.

Is there a setting in Visual Studio that allows us to specify that only the minimized version of the file be published when selecting the "Publish" option within Solution Explorer???

**PLEASE NOTE:** I am NOT asking for an MSBuild or MSDeploy solution (this is NOT a web APPLICATION; it is a website project) -- I want to be able to publish a single file at a time (in this case javascript) but I do NOT want the main source file published -- only the minified version.

The only solution I have found is to manually publish the minified version, and then manually delete the "source" file from the web site; but it would be nice if Visual Studio had a setting that would prevent the javascript "source" file from being uploaded to the server.

Perhaps no such option exists?  (Guess I am just looking for confirmation).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to use Web Essentials (http://vswebessentials.com/) and go to Web Essentials => Edit Global JSCS Settings (.jscssrc) and add

```
"excludeFiles": ["scripts/myfile.js","app/services/*", "app/controllers/*"]
```

More info here: [How can I configure Web Essentials 2013 to ignore files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499526/how-can-i-configure-web-essentials-2013-to-ignore-files)

Comment: Yes, thanks -- I came across this while searching as well.   I really would like to see an option whereby we could simply toggle (or mark) which files get published and which do not via solutions explorer in Visual Studio -- such a feature would be most welcome for those of us that have to maintain small website projects.